# How do you replace a string with a hash collection value in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have a hash collection:
`my_hash = {"1" => "apple", "2" => "bee", "3" => "cat"}`

What syntax would I use to replace the first occurrence of the `key` with hash collection `value` in a string?

eg my input string:
`str = I want a 3`

The resulting string would be:
`str = I want a cat`

Comment: What assumptions are there about the input string?  Generally, template languages like this mark it in some way, like `str = I want a {3}` (.NET string formatting).

Comment: Stack Overflow is not "please code this for me"; what is your code so far? What are your questions?

Comment: ...apparently I'm wrong. As evidenced below, apparently we are all so desperate to help that we hand out code to new users. Welcome to Stack Overflow! ;)

Comment: I would use Ruby 2.0's built in string templating feature if at all possible. Given a hash with symbol keys, `h = {pet: "cat"}` you can do this: `"I want a %{pet}" % h #=> "I want a cat"`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

My one liner:

```
hash.each { |k, v| str[k] &&= v }
```

or using `String#sub!` method:

```
hash.each { |k, v| str.sub!(k, v) }
```

Comment: +1 (when I get the votes) for the useage of `String#[]=` and `&&=`.

Comment: Can some one explain what the first one liner does?

Comment: As boolean operators in Ruby are short-circuited the second argument is evaluated if and only if the first one is true. The `String#[]` if has given string it find it and return sub-string reference to it. So if we assign something to it we will change given part of the string. Finally we join it together and if sub-string is found in string then substitute it with hash value.

Comment: Lukasz, nice work. One correction: you need to use the 'sub!' method rather than the 'sub' method in order for your second example to work. 'sub!' alters the string in place. (Or use 'gsub!' to replace *all* occurrences of the match in the string.)

Answer (score 17):

```
"I want a %{b}" % {c: "apple", b: "bee", a: "cat"}
=> "I want a bee"
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming Ruby 1.9 or later:

```
str.gsub /\d/, my_hash
```

Answer (score 3):

I didn't understand your problem, but you can try this:

```
my_hash = {"1" => "apple", "2" => "bee", "3" => "cat"}
str = "I want a 3"
str.gsub(/[[:word:]]+/).each do |word|
  my_hash[word] || word
end
#=> "I want a cat"
```

:D

Comment: IMHO it's a little bit overloaded.

Comment: Heh, I like this one for turning my head upside down. (I'd +1 you, but I'm out for the day. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Just to add point free style abuse to fl00r's answer:

```
my_hash = {"1" => "apple", "2" => "bee", "3" => "cat"}
my_hash.default_proc = Proc.new {|hash, key| key}
str = "I want a 3"
str.gsub(/[[:word:]]+/).each(&my_hash.method(:[]))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
my_hash = {"1" => "apple", "2" => "bee", "3" => "cat"}
str = "I want a 3"
```

If there isn't any general pattern for the strings you want to substitute, you can use:

```
str.sub /#{my_hash.keys.map { |s| Regexp.escape s }.join '|'}/, my_hash
```

But if there is one, the code becomes much simpler, e.g.:

```
str.sub /[0-9]+/, my_hash
```

If you want to substitute all the occurrences, not only the first one, use gsub.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String.sub](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-sub) in ruby 1.9:

```
string.sub(key, hash[key])
```

Comment: @Oleksi You meant `hash` not `hash[key]`
i.e.

    my_hash = {"1" => "apple", "2" => "bee", "3" => "cat"}
    my_str = 'I want a 3'
    puts my_str.sub('3', my_hash) # => 'I want a cat'

Answer (score 0):

The following code replace the first occurrence of the `key` with hash collection `value` in the given string `str`

```
 str.gsub(/\w+/) { |m| my_hash.fetch(m,m)}
    => "I want a cat"
```

Comment: It would improve the quality of your answer if you could provide more of an explanation of what your code does.  Why should someone try your code, is there something which can help them understand what they need to do?

Comment: explanation added