# Modify a string based on a hash

Tags: ruby

I want to convert a string based on a hash. For e.g., the string `"assistant director"` gets converted to `"asst dir"` when the hash contains `"assistant"=>"asst"` and `"director"=>"dir"`. I want to do something like:

```
hash = Hash["executive"=>"exec","assistant"=>"asst","associate"=>"assoc","director"=>"dir"]
str = "assistant director"

hash.each { |k, v| str.gsub!(k, v) }  
# => "asst dir"
```

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10080692/),

```
hash.each { |k, v| str.gsub!(k, v) }
```

should be the answer. But it doesn't return the converted string. And neither does `str` get changed.

Comment: @BroiSatse final_str doesn't return anything

Answer (score 4):

Another way of doing this is :-

```
str.gsub!(/\w+/, hash)
```

[`String#gsub!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-gsub-21)

> If the second argument is a Hash, and the matched text is one of its keys, the corresponding value is the replacement string.

Answer (score 2):

`hash.each { |k, v| str.gsub!(k, v) }` will return `hash.to_a`, but it doesn't matter as youa re using `gsub!` which means that your `str` is changed in place. Simply do:

```
hash.each { |k, v| str.gsub!(k, v) }  
str     #=> "asst dir"
```

Comment: @BroiSatse weird, so if str="Director", then hash.each { |k, v| str.downcase.gsub!(k, v) } doesn't work?

Comment: @echan00 - It's not weird, `gsub!` modifies given instance of string in place. `downcase` on the other hand creates a new string instance, so your `gsub!` modifies that instance instead of your original string. It should be enough to call `str.downcase!` once before iteration to fix it. (Note the bang - string will be modified in place again.

Comment: thanks! it was the downcase that was what was tripping me up!